# CSS3 keyframes in stylesheet

Tags: css

I found a nice tutorial on css3 transitions by richard bradshaw which can be found at
http://css3.bradshawenterprises.com/cfimg/

I am trying to set up my Master Page (ASP.Net 4) with a div that has 3 images transitioning
Visual Studio 2010 doesn't like the following keyframes directives AT ALL why? I am set on html5 and css3.

```
@-webkit-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
25% {
    opacity:1;
}
75% {
    opacity:0;
}
 100% {
   opacity:0;
 }
}

@-moz-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {
 0% {
   opacity:1;
 }
25% {
    opacity:1;
}
75% {
    opacity:0;
}
 100% {
   opacity:0;
 }
}
```

Here is the animation code;

```
.logotransitions img.top {
       -webkit-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -webkit-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 18s;
    -webkit-animation-direction: alternate;

    -moz-animation-name: cf3FadeInOut;
    -moz-animation-timing-function: ease-in-out;
    -moz-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -moz-animation-duration: 18s;
    -moz-animation-direction: alternate;
}
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the nice comments! Before you get too far into this, I really wouldn't implement it like this, as there isn't any fallback for browsers that don't support animations. That means to get cross browser compat, you'll need to write some Javascript. If you use jQuery, you can use their .animate() method in old browsers, and .css() in new ones + transitions to get the same behaviour without much trouble.

Comment: Richard, any reason why VS2010 doesn't like your @keyframe directives? The editor is red squigglying the directive code

Comment: Most likely the editor just isn't familiar with the syntax - Microsoft have only just implemented them in IE10. I'd guess that the new VS will have syntax info for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Those are just the animation definitions... you still need to declare that your targeted elements use that animation :

```
div {
    -webkit-animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite;
    -moz-animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite;
    animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite;
}
```

By the way, unless you're targeting only webkit & mozilla browsers, you should update your code (definitions & declarations) to include all the browser vendors :

```
div {
    -webkit-animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite; /*webkit*/
    -o-animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite; /*opera*/
    -moz-animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite; /*mozzila*/
    -ms-animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite; /*ie*/
    animation : cf3FadeInOut 1s ease infinite; /*no vendor*/
}

/*...*/
@-o-keyframes cf3FadeInOut {/*...*/}
/* ... and so on*/
```